# SQL Query is correct, yet does not fill Data Table

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms

I am attempting to fill a datatable with the following query:

```
SELECT 
    recipes.Name, Instructions, recipes.Preperation_Time, Author 
FROM 
    RecipeIngredients
INNER JOIN 
    recipes ON recipes.Recipe_ID = RecipeIngredients.Recipe_ID
INNER JOIN 
    Ingredients ON Ingredients.Ingredient_ID = RecipeIngredients.Ingredient_ID
WHERE 
    ingredients.Name IN ('eggs')
```

When I run this query inside an .sql file I get the desired results:

[image]

However, when I attempt to fill a datatable with the query, I do not get any results. This is not an issue with my database nor the code as when I use a simple query, such as:

```
"Select * FROM recipes"
```

I get all recipes inside my datagridview:

[image]

Am I missing something here?

Here is my code for the form and the Database connections class.

```
private void resultsWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Format ingredient array for SQL Syntax
    for(int i = 0; i< ingredientCount; i++)
    {
        string ing = ingredientArray[i];
        string editedIng = "'" + ing + "'";
        ingredientArray[i] = editedIng;
    }

    string ingredientString = string.Join(", ", ingredientArray);

    // get connection string
    string connectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString;

    DataTable recipeDataTable = new DataTable();
    conn = new DatabaseConnections(connectionString);

    conn.openConnection();

    // Get datatable
    recipeDataTable = conn.getRecipes(ingredientString);

    // Display data in grid view
    recipesDataGrid.DataSource = recipeDataTable;
    recipesDataGrid.Refresh();
}

public DataTable getRecipes(string ingredientString)
{
    string sqlString = ("SELECT recipes.Name, Instructions, recipes.Preperation_Time, Author FROM RecipeIngredients" +
                           " INNER JOIN recipes ON recipes.Recipe_ID = RecipeIngredients.Recipe_ID" +
                           " INNER JOIN Ingredients ON Ingredients.Ingredient_ID = RecipeIngredients.Ingredient_ID" +
                           " WHERE ingredients.Name IN ('eggs')");

    string sqlString_ = ("Select * FROM recipes");

    DataTable recipeDataTable = new DataTable();

    openConnection();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString_, connectionToDB);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    // Fill dataset
    da.Fill(recipeDataTable);

    closeConnection();

    return recipeDataTable;
}
```

Comment: It looks like it should work.  I suspect either the wrong server is being used or the default table is wrong.  You can add "Use database" to the query to see if you are using correct table.  More likely you have more than one mdf file.  The connection string should never have the mdf file.  Just specify the server name an instance to the name in the connection string.  Do not have an attach statement.  The database is already attached.

Comment: @jdweng I tried Use Database and it made no difference to the outcome

Comment: @goldenpeng The syntax looks good.  Can you SELECT * FROM Ingredient to see if 1)  it contains data and 2)  It's not spelled 'Eggs';

Comment: @JimCastro Yep that helped, I hadn't capitalised the E in Eggs... My query works now. Now I'm just trying to stop getting duplicate results from the query. Thanks.

Comment: @jdwengThe USE Database actually does make difference so ignore my last comment.My Query now works, but now my worry is that if this program is sent to others, that string will not work as it is unique to my computer, is there any way to do it so it will work across systems?

Comment: It is not unique to your computer, it is unique to the names of the databases in the server.  You can put the default database in the connection string instead of using the USE.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't try your code, but probably you just added the data in the table and it's not yet validated.
Could you try this statement in your T-SQL editor:

> COMMIT TRANSACTION;